# leave one out in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am very new in this field. I am using spyder  to run my code: I am trying to run simple leave one out cross validation code from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut

X = [1, 2 ,3, 4]
loo = LeaveOneOut()
for train, test in loo.split(X):
     print ("%s %s" %(train, test))
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I understand the reason, but do not know what to pass here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass total number of elements in dataset. The following code for your reference

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut

X = np.array([1, 2 ,3, 4])
loo = LeaveOneOut(4)
for train_idx, test_idx in loo:
    print X[train_idx], X[test_idx]
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the import line for `LeaveOneOut` to

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
```

([See documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html)). Then your code should work.

If you want to import it from `sklearn.cross_validation` then the syntax is a bit different ([see here](http://jaquesgrobler.github.io/Online-Scikit-Learn-stat-tut/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html)).